# Is there a way to get details of a build from Github Action Run Number

Tags: github, github-api

Given a repo(e.g. `envoyproxy/envoy`) and a `GITHUB_RUN_ID` (.e.g `2260986839`), I can get the details of this build by

```
curl -s -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/envoyproxy/envoy/actions/runs/2260986839
```

However, workflow run id is not as well placed and advertised in the repo as a workflow run number. It is available as `GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER` in the action run context.

Is there any github rest api endpoint, that provides details of a build run(including the commit reference sha) given the repo name, workflow id(e.g. `codeql-push.yml`) and the run number(e.g. `36676`)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking to get the commit SHA from a run_number...